# Displaying blank spaces in caesar cipher in C++

Tags: c++

I'm using a Caesar cipher IN C++ to encrypt code. The Caesar cipher can encrypt input with blank spaces but doesn't display the blank spaces instead it encrypts the blanks with letters, but it can decrypt it back to the original with blank spaces. I cant get it to display the blank spaces.

```
void EncryptionMachine::CaesarEncrypt()//Caesars encryption method
{
getline(cin,InputString);
cout<<"Encrypted string: "<<endl;
int CaesarIndex;
int shift=3;
int AlphaNumericIndex;

for (unsigned int i=0;i<InputString.length();i++)//nested for loop to go through both input string 
and alphabet
{
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<AlphaString.length();j++)
    {

    if(InputString[i]==AlphaString[j])
    {
        AlphaNumericIndex=j;
        CaesarIndex=(AlphaNumericIndex+shift)%26;//modulus to rotate the alphabet
        cout<<AlphaString[CaesarIndex];
        CaesarEncryptionString[i]=AlphaString[CaesarIndex];//array to save the data
        result=result+AlphaString[CaesarIndex];
    }
}

}
cout<<endl;

}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Can you explain how you think this is supposed to be handling spaces?

Comment: My alphabet has 26 plaintext characters and a space in it but still cant get it to display the blanks, it completely ignores it

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to encrypt/decrypt Caesar cipher escaping the space chars is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    string plainText;
    string codedText;
    int key = 3;

    void code() {
        codedText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++)
            if (plainText[i] != ' ')
                codedText += ( plainText[i] - 'A' + key ) % 26 + 'A';
            else
                codedText += ' ';
        cout << "|-> " << codedText << " <-|\n";
    }

    void decode() {
        plainText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < codedText.length(); i++)
            if (codedText[i] != ' ')
                plainText += ( codedText[i] - 'A' - key ) % 26 + 'A';
            else
                plainText += ' ';
        cout << "|-> " << plainText << " <-|\n";
    }  

    int main() {
        cout << "Insert text to code: ";
        getline(cin, plainText);
        code();
        decode();
        return 0;
    }
```

Of course, in the `if` clause you can add also other chars.